# what design pattern for pre-do in class function

Tags: python, design-patterns

My class function alway need do something before like this (Python):

```
class X:
 def f1():
  #### 
  if check() == False: 
   return;
  set_A()
  ####
  f1_do_something

 def f2():
  #### 
  if check() == False: 
   return;
  set_A()
  ####

  f2_do_something
```

And I want to :

```
class X:
 def f1():
  # auto check-return-set_A()
  f1_do_something

 def f2():
  # auto check-return-set_A() 
  f2_do_something
```

I've read about [design patterns](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx) and I do not know how to apply design patterns in this case. If there is no any suitable design patterns, are there any other solution to this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a [decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def check(f, *args, **kwargs):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print 'checking...'
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner

class Example(object):

    @check
    def hello(self):
        print 'inside hello'

    @check
    def hi(self):
        print 'inside hi'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    example = Example()
    example.hello()
    example.hi()
```

This snippet would print:

```
checking...
inside hello
checking...
inside hi
```

If you go this route, please check out [`functools.wrap`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.wraps), which makes decorators aware of the original function's name and documentation.

Comment: I suggest decorate your decorator with the function decorator decorator: http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.wraps

Comment: @AndersWaldenborg, thanks, added a note to my post. I haven't added it directly in the code, because I wanted to keep it as simple as possible to focus on the idea.